# AMD ATI driver - atikmdag.sys causing BSODs

Tags: windows-7, bsod, amd-radeon, display-driver

For the past two years I've been having problems with ATI drivers on Win7. From what I can gather, it's caused by ATI drivers. I have AMD Radeon Sapphire HD 7750 Ultimate Edition 128-bit 1GB DDR5 graphic card.

I've been getting BSODs a few times a month for the past two years. The problem has persisted through at least two or three versions of ATI drivers.

There are a lot of Google results referencing people having BSODs and atikmdag.sys problems, and a lot of different solutions but so far nothing I've done has helped.

What I've tried:

- Reinstalling ATI drivers; this seems to be the most common advice. I've tried newest ATI drivers, newest ATI drivers after cleaning up behind ATI drivers, Windows drivers, several versions of ATI drivers, third party drivers.
- Disabling hardware acceleration in Flash (but Flash doesn't seem to be related or even running when this happens).
- Installing all Windows updates.
- Reinstalling Windows.
- As this is three monitor setup; trying to use only two monitors, only one monitor; not using HDMI port.
- Replacing memory.
- Replacing graphic card.
- Praying.

What I haven't tried:

- Different motherboard.
- Different OS (it seems that running Linux doesn't have the same problems but I haven't run it longer than a day or two exclusively on Linux to be able to confirm this with certainty).

Minidump can be downloaded [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/243004/062315-13962-01.dmp), and I'm pasting WinDbg output below:

---

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\062315-13962-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.18869.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150525-0603
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02a57000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`02c9e730
Debug session time: Tue Jun 23 17:03:29.242 2015 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 22:24:12.302
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.........
Unable to load image atikmdag.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atikmdag.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for atikmdag.sys
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000007E, {ffffffffc0000005, fffff8800f2d4160, fffff88003ec3e88, fffff88003ec36e0}

Probably caused by : atikmdag.sys ( atikmdag+cd160 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)
This is a very common bugcheck.  Usually the exception address pinpoints
the driver/function that caused the problem.  Always note this address
as well as the link date of the driver/image that contains this address.
Some common problems are exception code 0x80000003.  This means a hard
coded breakpoint or assertion was hit, but this system was booted
/NODEBUG.  This is not supposed to happen as developers should never have
hardcoded breakpoints in retail code, but ...
If this happens, make sure a debugger gets connected, and the
system is booted /DEBUG.  This will let us see why this breakpoint is
happening.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
Arg2: fffff8800f2d4160, The address that the exception occurred at
Arg3: fffff88003ec3e88, Exception Record Address
Arg4: fffff88003ec36e0, Context Record Address

Debugging Details:
------------------


EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

FAULTING_IP: 
atikmdag+cd160
fffff880`0f2d4160 488b4130        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+30h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff88003ec3e88 -- (.exr 0xfffff88003ec3e88)
ExceptionAddress: fffff8800f2d4160 (atikmdag+0x00000000000cd160)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000030
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000030

CONTEXT:  fffff88003ec36e0 -- (.cxr 0xfffff88003ec36e0)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=fffffa8009c467e0 rsi=fffff8a010983708 rdi=0000000000000001
rip=fffff8800f2d4160 rsp=fffff88003ec40c8 rbp=fffffa800a91e318
 r8=0000000000040000  r9=0000000000000001 r10=fffff80002a57000
r11=fffff88003ec3ff0 r12=fffffa800b3dd010 r13=0000000000000000
r14=fffffa800a665a01 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010286
atikmdag+0xcd160:
fffff880`0f2d4160 488b4130        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+30h] ds:002b:00000000`00000030=????????????????
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000030

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002d08100
 0000000000000030 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
atikmdag+cd160
fffff880`0f2d4160 488b4130        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+30h]

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7E

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8800f33d539 to fffff8800f2d4160

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`03ec40c8 fffff880`0f33d539 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0a91e318 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`0d075198 : atikmdag+0xcd160
fffff880`03ec40d0 00000000`00000000 : fffffa80`0a91e318 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`0d075198 000000f4`10008000 : atikmdag+0x136539


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  atikmdag+cd160

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: atikmdag

IMAGE_NAME:  atikmdag.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  546ea3c3

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xfffff88003ec36e0 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_atikmdag+cd160

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x7E_atikmdag+cd160

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: try the new 15.6 Beta driver: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 Will do, but I've upgraded drivers regularly as new versions have come out and I don't think switch to beta will help me much, especially as it deals with "optimizations for Batman™: Arkham Knight" which I don't really play. :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried checking your system memory and ssd/hdd? sometimes the driver can crash by a corruption in the system memory or disk

try taking out one stick of ram and change os drive.. etc

also try running GPU-Z and see if its overheats
http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/

Comment: Thanks for response! During this time, I have both upgraded memory from 4GB to 8GB (changing all sticks in the process) and changed system disk from HDD to SDD, re-installing Windows and drivers in the process so it's unlikely it's due to memory/disk/file corruption. I've also ruled out GPU overheating, temperature was below 45 for most of this crashes, and some of them were when GPU was idle (and displays were in sleep mode).